# Colonial Policing via contracts. Is it a good idea?

Tags: internal-consistency

In Warlords the outer colonies are independent from the Hegemony and full of various colonies divided between dozens of factions. In the outer colonies policing is done by the "Colonial Marshals" who originally where peacekeepers from the Hegemony, but in the modern era are contractors, thugs, hired guns, etc.

In my mind each colony would have a contract of sorts for its "Colonial Marshals" who would enforce commonly agreed laws across the outer colonies. They would also be able to hunt down convicts across borders and through space.  As well as posting and paying out bounties.

Would policing this way be feasible? Or is a system like this too disorganised to work?

Notes:

multiple law firms and private armies exist that have bought or been offered multiple contracts

A enforcement branch exists to deal Marshalls that go too far or are publicly caught in somesort of scheme or conspiracy.

Comment: Contracts with individuals, or companies?  And how is this that much different from private security companies?

Comment: Usually companies, but you could hire a individual as part of a contract. Last time I checked private security has limited jurisdiction while the Marshals have real legal authority.

Comment: So, this is just private security companies that have been assigned legal authority.

Comment: For some of the groups yes. Some could be a local syndicate or gang for the poorer colonies

Comment: As to whether it's a good idea... this is the Libertarian fantasy.  I don't think it's a good idea, though.

Comment: The outer colonies I use as a commentary on certain politics. The Colonial Marshals are in my mind explaining how corrupt libertarianism can get, but also tapping into "Blade Runner" and "Aliens" vibes.

Comment: "*in my mind explaining how corrupt libertarianism can get*".  It seems that you're asking for our opinions on sociopolitical theories,

Comment: (a) It is unclear what you're asking.  What is your specific, definable question?  (b) We contract with private individuals to provide law enforcement today (they're called employment contracts).

Comment: @RonJohn not necessarily. I'm asking if the system itself would work because I want my world to have a semblance of reality.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the Cato Institute has written a number of research reports on contract policing.

Comment: @JBH a: I'm asking if this policing system would work. B: I would like to say that employing a person as a cop is different then giving private security or a hired gun legal authority (seeing as local cops exist in the colonies)

Comment: @RonJohn I'll take a look

Comment: The short answer is yes-and-no. It'll work to make PMCs and bounty hunters rich. It'll work to neutralize enemies of The Hegemony. It'll work to secure something resembling justice for affluent victims. But for the working-classes of your world, this won't be an efficient justice system. But that might not be the point. One of my settings uses DROs and PMCs exclusivelh, and nobody with leverage actually cares whether or not it works for their lower classes. So the answer is contextual to who's justice is being sought here...sadly the same as real world legal systems.

Comment: Also keep in mind The Cato Institute is an advocacy group *cough-cough-propaganda-outlet*, so anything you take from them is a good idea of what laissez faire proposals are like, _not_ how they would necessarily work if put into practice. Use your best judgement, and other sources, when interpreting likely the effects of their proposals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll work insofar as the locals want it to work.

Outside the central jurisdiction, such a person would be at the whim of local power structures. Politicians, militias, gangsters, corporations, religious leaders, would all have more contextual power than any given marshal, and a connected criminal would mean that a foreign marshal is not just going up against that criminal, but local bastions of power.

Marshals would have to be highly diplomatic, and know how to ingratiate themselves within diverse social contexts.

They'd want to maintain near constant contact with Home Base, to ensure that if they get lynched, the power of the Hegemony would be brought down.

They'd be highly proficient killers. In a military context, you might want to look at special forces for ideas, because they fulfill a similar niche, IRL.

They'd be endemically corrupt. Far from the Hegemony, they have near limitless discretion, and little reason to risk apprehending a powerful target if the locals will simply pay them to go away or collaborate. No oversight body will be able to stop this, and your DROs (law firms) will be just as corrupt. This branch will likely exist purely to siphon money into a Military-Carceral-Industrial-Complex.

I'd imagine they would be expected to be corrupt and slick, but incredibly dangerous if they can't be bought.

As far as feasibility: this is basically a bounty hunter. This model has been used IRL, but more coherent and pliable polities may have extradition arrangements with The Hegemony, which is also how this works IRL. If that's the case, and the Hegemony has the ability to extradite, these marshals would, basically, be spies, not LEOs. Instead of Marshals, local law enforcement would apprehend criminals in any areas with extradition. Which means the only places the Marshals would be sent are actively hostile to the Hegemony, where they have no local support and no backup. Imagine the CIA or JSOC trying to capture a mark in...say North Korea.
So, it seems like you have two major pathways to go:

Traditional bounty hunter who may or may not be aboveboard, in a setting of constant moral ambiguity and horrific corruption.

Or

Straightlaced operative sent by the space-feds into hostile territory.

Which of these is most reasonable very much depends on how you've built your world. I think that the first option seems to fit the vibe I'm getting for your project, but it means you'd have to do some calibration of The Hegemony. A superpower capable of, and interested in, sending out law enforcement outside its borders, but which *isn't* able to create extradition arrangements is a interesting needle to thread.
I'd imagine The Hegemony itself would have to be a waning power, or even outright weak, with this system kept alive by powerful and vested, economic interests.
Or the specific targets would have to be very high value.

Comment: In my mind the Hegemony lost its grip on the outer colonies and the Marshals are the last bastion of Hegemony rule in the outer colonies. I do really like your answer though.

Comment: @CelestialDragonEmperor Does The Hegemony have the ability to garrison troops in these places?

Comment: the Hegemony is able to garrison some troops in stations or moon's it controls in the outer colonies. Most are in the belt or are Jovian, ex: Themisto

Comment: This might be important. If The Hegemony has lost control over these regions, they might not even care about law enforcement in rogue colonies. Their first agenda would be re-asserting political and economic control. If they can garrison troops in the colonies, they'd probably smash the insurrections one at a time. Move significant troop presence in, quell local dissidents. Replace power structures, and Marshals might ride that wave, either accompanying the occupiers during these conflicts or being dispatched to pacified territories to enforce hegemony rule.

Comment: I guess you'd have to shore up the capacities and socio-economic motivations here to get an idea of who would want this system and how it would be deployed.

Comment: right now I know that corporations and business elite enjoy the benefits of being able to hunt down debters. Local "bosses" and some civilians also enjoy a semblance of order in the colonies.

Comment: There you go, then. Option A it is. 